# write and read integers to/from a text file

Tags: java, file-io, integer, text-files

I need to write integer values to a text file. Then I'll need to read such file to recover the integer values. I've seen several approaches to do this but I was wondering which is the most appropriate for writing integers? Note that the text may be large but less than 1 million values. The values are written and read one at a time.

Comment: can you show us the approaches?

Comment: NIO maybe help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @clph3r For example, should I use a FileInputStream or a FileReader when using a buffered reader? or should I use a scanneer?

Comment: None of these will help you *write* integers.

Comment: .. and you could use xml, raw-bytes, java-serialzation-api, plain-ascii,.. to serialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to just write them with println (using e.g. a PrintStream), then read them with a Scanner. The file will be human-readable too.

Using a binary file would be more efficient, but you said you need a text file.

Comment: +1 for printing a number per line. Works with other readers as well (e.g. `BufferedReader.readLine()`), but those would probably require conversion to `int` afterwards.

Comment: yes, that is actually a really simple way to achieve it, thanks